# Apex Method doesn't return any value

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, record

With this code I want to get the value of the myrecord (Volume__c). But with this code I don't get any value.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List <Volume__c> getObj(String recordId){
    Volume__c tt = [SELECT  Account__c, Account__r.Id FROM Volume__c where id=: recordId];
    String acct = tt.Account__r.id;
    List <Volume__c> Obj = [SELECT Id , Account__r.Name  ,Year__c, Family__c, Unit__c ,
    CreatedBy.Name ,LastModifiedDate
    FROM Volume__c WHERE Account__r.id =: acct];
        return Obj ;
}
```

```
 @track value = 'M3';
 @track stocks;
 tabs = [];

 get options() {
        return [
       { label: 'Liter', value: 'Liter' },
       { label: 'M3', value: 'M3' }
            
        ];
    }
   connectedCallback() {
        getObj().then(data => {
            this.stocks= data;
            this.stocks.forEach(stock=> {
                this.tabs.push({ 
                    Account__c: stock.Id, 
                   Family__c: 'aa', 
                    Unit__c: 'm3',
                    
                 });
                this.tabs.push({ 
                  Account__c: stock.Id, 
                   Family__c: 'cc', 
                    Unit__c: 'm3',
                 });
            });

        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('stock Error => : ' + error);
        })


    }
```

```
   <tbody for:each={stocks} for:item="stock" key={stock.Id}>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{stock.Name}</td>
<td>
<lightning-input style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="number" id={stock.Id} name="aa"  value={Name} ></lightning-input>
</td>
<td>
<lightning-input style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="text" disabled value={Label.acc}></lightning-input>
</td>
<td>
<lightning-combobox style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" value={value} options={options}
id={stock.Id} name="cc" onchange={handleUnitChange}></lightning-combobox>
</td>
<td>
<lightning-input style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="number" id={stock.Id}
 name="Fd" onchange={handleObjChange}></lightning-input>
</td>
<td>
<lightning-input style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="text" name="archivedValue"
 onchange={handleAchivedValue}></lightning-input>
 </td>
 <td>
<lightning-input style="width: 80%;margin-left: 10%;" type="text" name="progress"
onchange={handleProgress}></lightning-input>
                            </td>
 <tbody for:each={stocks} for:item="stock" key={stock.Id}>
<--
>
                        </tr>
    
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the apex class in your LWC? If not I suggest you do that first. `import getvolume from **put in the address here**`
After that make sure passs the record Id to that method.
To get the recordId of the record use `@api recordId` and pass it as a parameter like `getvolume({recordId : recordId}).then()` and manage the result in then().

Answer (score 0):

I would move to the use of a `wire` adapter for this, because you don't know when your `recordId` param is going to have data.

Make sure your Apex is cachable

```
@AuraEnabled(cachable = true)
```

Don't forget to define a recordId variable:

```
recordId
```

Empty the connected Callback:

```
connectedCallback(){
  //empty
}
```

Define your `@wire` like this:

```
@wire(getObject, { recordId: '$recordId'})
handleGetWiredObject({error,data}){
  if(!data){
    return;
  }
  this.stocks= data;
  this.stocks.forEach(stock=> {}
  ///etc
}
```

This means that when the recordId gets data, the `wire` will fire.

Oh and don't forget to import the method as mentioned above in the other answer.

Comment: thank you for your help , but when I modified the code I get this error :  ` LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')] `

Comment: Sorry fixed my wire defintion -see change to `{error,data}` in param